# Multiplying Permutation Groups in Cycle Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutation-cycles

I am given that f = (1 2 3 4 5 6) and g = (1 2). I am told to compute $f^2gf^4$. I know that $f^2 = (1 3 5)(2 4 6)$ and $f^4 = (1 5 3)(2 6 4)$. But I am having trouble computing the product of all three together. 
So far I have:
$$ f^2gf^4 = (1 3 5)(2 4 6)*(1 2)*(1 5 3)(2 6 4)  $$
$$f^2g = (1 4 6 2)(3 5)$$
then I computed that, 
$$f^2gf^4 = (13)$$

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: I get $(6342)$. I am prone to calculation errors, however. Always understood the material better than anyone in the class in high school but got $88$ on the test!

Comment: I think your computation of $f^2g$ is incorrect. It should just be one single cycle $f^2g = (146235)$. I'm getting a final answer of $(34)$.